# Xamarin forms Azure Authentication and Authorization using OpenID Connect

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I previously did the authentication in my xamarin forms app using OAuth2.0.

You can check the below link for refrence:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-active-directory-login-in-xamarin-forms/

Now i'm searching same kind of implementation in xamarin forms app using OpenID Connect.

Comment: OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 are very similar, OpenID Connect is an authentication layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol.According to the Azure openid connect, you could refer to this link.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/
You can refer to the following link with IdentityServer4.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/authentication-and-authorization

Comment: The one link you send that shows how to build a web app that uses OpenID Connect. And the other link is just a overview article of Authentication and Authorization, not having complete code flow. I'm looking for xamarin.forms using OpenID connect code flow.

Comment: I can not find Authorities using OpenID Connect with Azure, but i find a blog about Okta https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/01/add-authentication-xamarin-openid-connect